# Django rest framework 3 - organizing views with json and html

Tags: json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I know about http headers, if perform request with headers and put to headers text line about content type with 'json', it can be detected within python views.py

My question is about django-rest-framework3, i need to know how i can use the same view for displaying html if it is regular browser request, and for api json, if it was requested from javascript.

How to make view universal for two of these data types, how to make code looks compact, i don't want double code, separate one view for json and second for html.

Or maybe i'm wrong? Should i separate these views?

I like reusable apps method. I always do this. And i want make my app to be good and single feature website files should putted in one folder to make it reusable

Answer (score 0):

DRF has a concept of [parsers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/) and [renderers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/) which will deal with the interaction with the client based on the content-type.

Therefore, you have `FormParser` / `JSONParser` for inputs for HTML forms and JSON. You also have `JSONRenderer` for returning JSON as well as `TemplateHTMLRenderer` for HTML pages.